# margin-top doesn't work

Tags: css

Here's a simplest html document. I specify `margin-top` at the `h1` style. Here's the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Free mind!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      p {
        font-family : DejaVu Sans Mono;
        font-size : 12pt;
        line-height : 100%;
        margin-top : 0cm;
        margin-bottom : 0.3cm;
        white-space : pre-wrap;
        display : inline;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size : 14pt;
        line-height : 100%;
        margin-top : 1cm;
        display : inline;
        color : blue ; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bio</h1>
      <p>
bk-simulates-range.py -S &quot;&quot; -b &quot;&quot; -e &quot;&quot; -s &quot;&quot; -t dspc.top -n 3000000 -c -j bk-runs-mpi.bash -w &quot;-4.5.5-double_gcc&quot; 2&amp;&gt; `date +%Y-%b-%d-%H%M%S`.log &amp; 
bk-pymol-selects.py -f confout.gro -s &quot;resi 1-128&quot; -t traj.trr -i 50 
bk-pymol-selects.py -f *ane.gro
bk-pymol-pic.py -f confout.gro -s &quot;resi 1-128&quot; -x &quot;-2&quot; -y &quot;-3&quot; -z &quot;0&quot; -t traj.trr
       </p>
     <h1>Bash</h1>
       <p>
cd /new/dir; (cd /old/dir; find -type d ! -name .) | xargs mkdir
for i in `ls`; do  $i; done
       </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm for this question must be really simple.

**Edit**:

So the problem was:

```
display : block;
```

in the `h1` specification. I ended up using (here I quote `head` and the `body` - other parts require no changes):

```
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Free mind!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      p {
        font-family : DejaVu Sans Mono;
        font-size : 12pt;
        line-height : 100%;
        margin-top : 0px;
        margin-bottom : 0px;
        white-space : pre-wrap;
        display : inline;
      }
        h1 {
        font-size : 14pt;
        line-height : 100%;
        margin-top : 20px;
        margin-bottom : -1px;
        display : block;
        color : blue ; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bio</h1>
      <p>bk-simulates-range.py -S &quot;&quot; -b &quot;&quot; -e &quot;&quot; -s &quot;&quot; -t dspc.top -n 3000000 -c -j bk-runs-mpi.bash -w &quot;-4.5.5-double_gcc&quot; 2&amp;&gt; `date +%Y-%b-%d-%H%M%S`.log &amp; 
bk-pymol-selects.py -f confout.gro -s &quot;resi 1-128&quot; -t traj.trr -i 50 
bk-pymol-selects.py -f *ane.gro
bk-pymol-pic.py -f confout.gro -s &quot;resi 1-128&quot; -x &quot;-2&quot; -y &quot;-3&quot; -z &quot;0&quot; -t traj.trr</p>
     <h1>Bash</h1>
       <p>cd /new/dir; (cd /old/dir; find -type d ! -name .) | xargs mkdir
for i in `ls`; do  $i; done</p>
  </body>
```

Also people say that `em` and `px` should be used instead of `cm` and `pt` - for `cm` and `pt` are no good for the web.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's wrong?

Comment: @paulmorriss: Oh - I'm sorry. The wrong is the margin of `h1` of the code above. It is not `1cm` as it has to be according to the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h1 { 
    font-size : 14pt; 
    line-height : 100%; 
    margin-top : 1cm; 
    display : block;      /*changed*/
    color : blue ;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You made your h1 element inline and margin won't be affected by that.

Note that your settings in cm and pt are for print, not the web.

Answer (score 1):

change to use: `display : inline-block;`

EDIT: some notes:

Margins will not be supported without layout on the element.  Three different ways to do that would be to use `display:block;`, use `display: inline-block;` or to use the existing `display:inline;` but then add a new `zoom:1;` to the style.   Note that `display:inline-block;` might not be fully supported on all browsers, but all modern ones should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You're displaying `h1` and `p` elements as inline.
Margins are better suited to block elements.

If you need to use inline, you try using padding on the `h1` instead of a margin.

Also, you shouldn't use the units, `pt` and `cm` for display, you should stick with `px` and `em`.

```
h1 {
    font-size : 14pt;
    padding-top : 1cm;
    display : inline;
    color : blue ; 
}
```